# Background image of html button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create HTML button with some text and also want to put background image for that button.I am trying following code but thats not working. I have placed test.png in my www directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" name="test" value="test" style="background:url('test.png') no-repeat 0 0; width:100px;height=50px;background-color: transparent" ></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your image url is not correct

Comment: Is image in the same folder where your HTML is?

Comment: I tried with something like http://localhost/test.png also but that was also not working

Comment: yes its in same folder ..its in www

Comment: Have you checked console?? i mean is it showing normal button?

Comment: Both your HTML and CSS are invalid. Please do [basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/). (Those errors shouldn't actually impact this problem though, the code as given should give the desired effect).

Comment: Open it with firebug or other developer tool (Chrome or Firefox), and hover in the url of your background, in CSS panel. The tool must show you a thumb of your background. If don't, it's something incorrect in the url.

Comment: @Stano — No, giving a lengths for the background-position is fine.

Comment: @Quentin oops my fault, you're right, i didn't checked the manual. usually i use those predefined constants.

Comment: its showing me thumbnail in firebug..but not shwoing background image on button

Comment: Cannot reproduce — http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/image/ — whatever your problem is, it isn't caused by something that you have described in your question. Voting to close as "Not a real question".

Comment: @Quentin: I can see its working for you but I am using same code and its not working for me..

Comment: whatever your problem is, it isn't caused by something that you have described in your question

Comment: thats what I am saying ...I am not doing anything specific here and this code should run correctly everywhere and I am trying to figure out the issue..

Comment: If I put http://localhost/test.png I can see image in browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used following HTML and everything works.

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="test" style=" background: url('http://www.training-industry.co.uk/assets/images/Take_Test.png') no-repeat 0 0;
width:130px;
height:130px;
background-color: transparent;" />
```

Look at this fiddle and compare with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ssqfK/1

Answer (score 0):

you have defined height like this `height=50px;` this is a wrong syntax.

Right syntax while writing css in style attribute: `height:50px;`

**Edited:**

Also check the path of the image is correct or the image exists on the given path.

Comment: That is true, but wouldn't prevent the background image from showing up.

Comment: It will help to show the background..

Comment: Only if the problem is that only *some* of the background is showing up.

Answer (score -1):

try `background-image` instead of `background`

Answer (score -1):

`background:url('test.png') no-repeat 0 0; width:100px; height=50px; background-color: transparent`

Should be:

`background:transparent url('test.png') no-repeat 0 0; width:100px; height:50px;"`

**On a side note**, you should try to avoid inline style where possible.

Comment: Make that `height:50px`, and I can agree :-)

Comment: The two lines of code are equivalent. It is permissible to omit the colour from the `background` property (in which case it defaults to `transparent`).

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="test" style="background:transparent url('test.png') no-repeat 0 0; width:100px;height:50px;" />
```

ALso, be careful with the height:50px instead of height=50px